# Добавление часов к дате с учетом всех переходов

Tags: c#, дата

Всем привет) Суть проблемы в том что нужно написать клас для установки времени от года до секунд(ето я сделал). + написать методы для прибавления к уже существующей дате часов,минут,секунд с учетом всех переходов чтобы я мог допустим прибавить 100500 часов и получить реальную дату.  Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
class DateControl
{
    private string year;
    private string mounth;
    private string day;
    private string hour;
    private string minutes;
    private string seconds;

    private bool isLeap = false;

    private int[] mn = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    public DateControl(string year)
    {

    }

    public string SetYear
    {
        set
        {
            int check = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            if (check < 0)
            {
                check = check * (-1);
            }
            if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(check))
            {
                isLeap = true;
            }
            this.year = Convert.ToString(check);
        }

        get {
            return this.year;
        }
    }

    /*public void setYear(string year)
    {
        int check = Convert.ToInt32(mounth);
        if (check < 0)
        {
            check = check * (-1);
        }
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(check))
        {
            isLeap = true;
        }
        this.year = Convert.ToString(check);
    }*/

    public void setMounth(string mounth)
    {
        int check= Convert.ToInt32(mounth);
        if(check<1 || check > 12)
        {
            showError();
        }
        else this.mounth = mounth;

    }

    public void setDay(string day)
    {
        int check = Convert.ToInt32(day);
        if (check < 1 || check > mn[Convert.ToInt32(mounth)])
        {
            showError();
        }
        else this.day = day;

    }

    public void setHour(string hour)
    {
        int check = Convert.ToInt32(hour);
        if (check < 0 || check > 23)
        {
            showError();
        }
        else this.hour = hour;

    }

    public void setMinute(string minutes)
    {
        int check = Convert.ToInt32(minutes);
        if (check < 0 || check > 59)
        {
            showError();

        }
        else this.minutes = minutes;

    }

    public void setSecond(string seconds)
    {
        int check = Convert.ToInt32(minutes);
        if (check < 0 || check > 59)
        {
            showError();
        }
        else this.seconds = seconds;

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //добавить часы
    public void addHours(string hourCount)
    {
        int reserve = Convert.ToInt32(hour) + Convert.ToInt32(hourCount);
        if (reserve <= 23)
        {
            this.hour = Convert.ToString(reserve);
            return;
        }else if (reserve > 23)
        {
          //дальше непонятно
        }

    }
    //добавить минуты 
    public void addMinutes(string hourCount)
    {

    }
    //секунды
    public void addSeconds(string hourCount)
    {

    }

    public void showError()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
    }

    public  string toString()
    {
        string reurnString = "" + year + "." + mounth + "." + day + "   " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        return reurnString;
    }
```

Comment: Вы знаете о существовании в C# типа `DateTime`?
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Такой метод уже существует: [`DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx). Не изобретайте велосипед.

Comment: @VladD в том то  и дело что нужно написать полностью свой клас со своими методами.

Comment: Если нужен *полностью* свой, тогда использование `DateTime.IsLeapYear` нечестно ;).

Comment: Так то оно так) Но мне  нужно знать как выполнить все переходы при прибавлении минут там или часов. в этом и суть вопроса

Comment: @Serhiy Уберите слово "просто" из предыдущего комментария. -1 за слово "банально" в вопросе.

Comment: Убрал))))))))))

Comment: @Serhiy: Написать собственный класс? Зачем? Если это реальная производственная задача, то берите готовый класс `DateTime` и не тратьте времени работодателя. Если это учебное задание, решайте его сами, иначе вы ничему не научитесь.

Comment: Согласен) Спасибо))